# adding custom Gutenberg block icon

Tags: gutenberg-blocks

I have added a static block for adding a shortcode. Instead of using the      dashicons as the block icon, I want to use a customized icon which is already existed in the plugin 'images' folder. Anyone please help me to use a .svg image as the block icon. Below is the code I have tried so far to add an customized icon

```
( function() {
var __ = wp.i18n.__;
var createElement = wp.element.createElement;
var registerBlockTypeMainPage = wp.blocks.registerBlockType;
const iconEl = el('svg', { width: 20, height: 20 },
    el('path', { d: "M8.54,4.68V8h3.23v.58H8.54v3.28H8V8.55H4.74V8H8V4.68Z,M26.48,5.93,24.15,8.26l2.28,2.28L26,11,23.74,8.66,21.42,11,21,10.58l2.33-2.32L21.05,6l.41-.41,2.28,2.28,2.33-2.33Z,M11.26,23.45V24h-6v-.59Z,M27.25,22.36v.58h-7v-.58Zm0,2.19v.57h-7v-.57Z" } )
);

registerBlockTypeMainPage(
    'mdlr/static-block',
    {
        title: __( 'Test block' ),
        icon: iconEl,
        category: 'widgets',

        edit: function( props ) {
            return createElement(
                'p',
                {
                    className: props.className,
                },
                '[test-block]'
            );
        },

        save: function( props ) {
            return createElement(
                'p',
                {
                    className: props.className,
                },
                '[test-block]'
            );
        },
    }
);
})();
```

Comment: I had a similar issue and found that I was missing the viewBox attribute. I'd give this a try.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52118306/how-do-i-use-a-font-awesome-icon-for-a-custom-gutenberg-block